# response other than true and false

Tags: json, ajax

I need response other than TRUE and FALSE just to display yet another message. like `echo json_encode(notloggedin);` in e.g below

```
public function watchlist(Request $request)
{
    if($request->ajax())
    {
            $source=new Book();
            $add->user_id=$request->id;
            if(!Auth::check())
            {            
                echo json_encode(notloggedin);die;                         
            }
            $add->save();        
            echo json_encode(TRUE);die;
        }

        echo json_encode(FALSE);die;
    }
}
```

ajax: so that i could do.

```
    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url: "{{url('/bookcontroller/book')}}",
        data: {id:id},
        success: function (data) {
            var response = $.parseJSON(data);
                if(response == true)
                {
                    swal("Book Added to list", "", "success");
                }

                else if(response == false)
                {
                    swal("Opps!", "Something went wrong!. Try again", "error");
                }

               else if(response == notloggedin)
              {
                   swal("Please login first", "", "error");
               }
```

Comment: is `notloggedin` a variable?? does it contain values other than `true/false`??

Comment: No. I just want to display another message if not logged in.@asif

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve it by slightly modifying your code as below:

```
public function watchlist(Request $request)
{
    if($request->ajax())
    {
            $source=new Book();
            $add->user_id=$request->id;
            if(!Auth::check())
            {            
                echo json_encode('notloggedin');die;    //if notloggedin is not a variable then you should put quote around it to make it string                     
            }
            $add->save();        
            echo json_encode(TRUE);die;
        }

        echo json_encode(FALSE);die;
    }
}
```

Here is modified ajax part:

```
    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url: "{{url('/bookcontroller/book')}}",
        data: {id:id},
        success: function (data) {
            var response = $.parseJSON(data);
                if(response === true)
                {
                    swal("Book Added to list", "", "success");
                }

                else if(response === false)
                {
                    swal("Opps!", "Something went wrong!. Try again", "error");
                }

               else if(response === 'notloggedin')
              {
                   swal("Please login first", "", "error");
               }
         }
    });
```